# Derivatives of Divided Differences

Tags: numerical-methods

> I want to show that
>   $$
> \frac{d}{dx} f[x_0,\ldots, x_k, u_1,\ldots, u_n] = \sum_{v=1}^n f[x_0,\ldots, x_k, u_1,\ldots, u_n, u_v] \frac{d u_v}{d x}
> $$
>   where $x_0,\ldots x_k$ are constants and $u_1,\ldots, u_n$ are differentiable functions of $x$.

I understand that
$$
f[x,x] = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} f[x,x+\epsilon]
= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon} = f'(x)
$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed when the divided difference has several arguments. In the following special case, would we write something like
$$
f[x,x,x] = \lim_{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\rightarrow 0} f[x,x+\epsilon_1,x+\epsilon_2]
= \lim_{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\rightarrow 0} 
\frac{f[x,x+\epsilon_2]-f[x,x+\epsilon_1]}{\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1}?
$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why the number of arguments changes in $f[]$?

Comment: @YuriyS I think its saying that when you differentiate a divided difference, you add an extra argument. Alternatively, its a way to make sense of repeated arguments in divided differences. For example $f[x,x] = f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f[x]$. Just not sure how to extend the proof to the general case :(